# PHP: Out of memory error after setting memory limit to -1

Tags: php, mysql, memory-management, memory-limit

I have a script in which I am fetching 725000 records at once and looping through to create array elements. Initially it says memory exhausted. Then, in my script I added-

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

After this, it throwing error-

```
Out of memory (allocated 1585446912) (tried to allocate 52 bytes)
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It looks like you're out of memory. Have much RAM do you have?

Comment: First check that your ISP allows you to change memory settings.... second, redesign your code to work with each record in turn rather than simply filling memory

Comment: You should consider optimizing your code or at least reducing the number of records it works with at a time; 1.5 GB is an insane amount of memory to be using for one script.

Comment: This code is in local environment and my PC has 3GB of RAM :(